# Android RestTemplate exchange() throws HttpClientErrorException: 401 Unauthorized

Tags: android, spring, unauthorized, spring-android

I am trying to connect to a RESTful web service from an Android client.

However, I always get a `HttpClientErrorException: 401 Unauthorized even if provide the correct authorization token in the request header.`

The url provided is correct.

I have also tried with this request factory:

```
template.setRequestFactory(new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory());
```

If i use Postman for Chorme with the same headers and url I get a response.

This is my code:

```
public class PutSomeObjectTask extends AsyncTask<SomeObject, Void, SomeObject>{

@Override
protected SomeObject doInBackground(SomeObject... params) {
    SomeObject object = params[0];
    String url = ...;

    RestTemplate template = new RestTemplate();
    template.setRequestFactory(new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory());
    template.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
    template.getMessageConverters().add(new FormHttpMessageConverter());

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.add("Content-Type", "application/json");
    headers.set("Authorization", AuthUtil.getCurrentUserAuthorization());

    HttpEntity<SomeObject> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<SomeObject>(object, headers);
    ResponseEntity<SomeObject> responseEntity = template.exchange(url, HttpMethod.PUT, requestEntity, SomeObject.class);

    return responseEntity.getBody();
}}
```

Comment: What does `AuthUtil.getCurrentUserAuthorization()` do?

Comment: AuthUtil.getCurrentUserAuthorization() returns the authorization token which has to be added to the request header.

Comment: Are you sure you construct the authorization token correctly?

Comment: I used the same token in Postman and I could connect to the service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. I just had to update Maven dependencies.